# jQuery csv file export fires multiple times

Tags: forms, javascript, ajax, importing-exporting

I have a custom form, and I just want a button in the form that fires a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin) that generates a csv file for download. The problem I'm having is that it seems to fire multiple times for some reason, and I haven't been able to figure out why. I've tried both a button and a link, but I keep getting the same result.

Here's the form button:

```
$form['export_csv_button'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => t('Export to CSV'),
);
```

And here's my jQuery behavior:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.ons_line_item_export = {
    attach: function (context) {
      $("#edit-export-csv-button").click(function() {
        $("#ons-line-item").tableExport({ type: "csv" });
        return false;
      })
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing that is making this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.ons_line_item_export = {
    attach: function (context) {
      $("#edit-export-csv-button").once().click(function() {
        $("#ons-line-item").tableExport({ type: "csv" });
        return false;
      })
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

I added the [`jQuery.once()`](https://www.drupal.org/node/444344) method.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. After reading the [d.o. issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/444344) that added that method, it made sense.